# ELIMINAR REGISTRO CUANDO 2 CAMPOS SON NULOS DATAFRAME

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Necesito eliminar un registro de un Dataframe SOLO cuando 2 valores de campos sean nulos, estoy trabajando en Pandas, estoy usando la función de Python .dropna() pero cuando le paso en el subset los 2 campos me elimina cuando almenos uno de los dos es nulo, es decir, realiza un OR, y quiero es un AND por asi decirlo, cuando AMBOS campos son nulos

```
df.dropna(subset=['CAMPO1','CAMPO2'], axis=0, inplace=True)
```

Muchas gracias!!

```
df.dropna(subset=['CAMPO1','CAMPO2'], axis=0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Probaste pasar el argumento [how="all"](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#:~:text=axis%20is%20allowed.-,how,-%7B%E2%80%98any%E2%80%99%2C%20%E2%80%98all%E2%80%99%7D%2C%20default)?

Comment: Era eso amigo, muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada Jonathan! Por cierto, para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas (o no hacer una pregunta en lo absoluto) siempre viene bien investigar, leer la documentacion, hacer un registro de lo que encuentres y recien ahi publicar la pregunta con dicho registro c: